# How to config WCF settings from 2 different web applications

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

I have a WCF project that send emails, log them, and know how to use templating.

There are 2 different web sites that have a service reference to this project, but they need also to provide a `From` address to the service which I don't want it to be send at each method call, I consider this to be a setting of the service behavior. What is the correct way to do it?

With referencing different project I can use the settings properties section in the `web.config`, but with WCF this solution won't work.

Comment: If I understand right, you want a different `From` address for each client, but you don't want it to be part of the service contract.  In this case, you could consider adding a custom behavior on the client side to generate a custom SOAP header, and a custom behavior on the server side to interpret it.

Comment: Well my question concerning the way to provide settings between services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly you just need common settings between multiple projects, right?

I would go with appsettings and Dependency Injection. It's origin is asp.net core but you could apply the principle anywhere.

For instance:
https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/08/16/diwithconfiguration/